# How can i publish nunit3 test result in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkinfile defined as below:

```
stages{
      stage("Unit Tests") {
        script {
          try {
            powershell "c:\\'Program Files (x86)'\\NUnit.org\\nunit-console\\nunit3-console.exe (ls -r *\\bin\\Debug\\*.UnitTests.dll | % { $_.FullName } | sort-object -Unique) --result=Caxton.OMX.DevelopBranch.UnitTests.xml"
          }
          catch (Exception err) {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
          }
        }

      stage("Integration Tests") {
        script {
          try {
            powershell "c:\\'Program Files (x86)'\\NUnit.org\\nunit-console\\nunit3-console.exe D:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\'Caxton.OMX (Build and run unit tests for develop branch)'\\Caxton.OMX.IntegrationTests\\bin\\Debug\\Caxton.OMX.IntegrationTests.dll --result=Caxton.OMX.DevelopBranch.IntegrationTests.xml"
          }
          catch (Exception err) {
            currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
          }
        }
}
```

Now, i want to publish those xml files in the post-build actions, what should i do? i do not know the parameters for the nunit3, but it should be something like this:

```
post{
   nunit3 testResultFile ' ' ...
}
```

Please provide me the details of the parameters of nunit3 in Jenkinfile, or even better with the example for this case (i want to publish both 2 xml files). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this. I add the following code to the post-build:

```
post
  {
    always
    {
      echo "publish the Nunit3 tests"
      step([
        $class: 'NUnitPublisher',
        testResultsPattern: "*.xml",
        debug: false,
        //keepJUnitReports: true,
        //skipJUnitArchiver:false,
        failOnError: true,
        //failIfNoResults: true
      ])
    }
  )
```

There are more parameters that you can add, but the tests can be published to Jenkins view with just the 3 above. Hope that can help anyone with the same problem as me.

Answer (score 0):

Using the snippet generator I came up with the following, which worked for me:
[image]

```
    post {
        always {
            nunit testResultsPattern: 'TestResult.xml'
        }
    }
```

After the job is run, go to the build and you should see a test report there listing all the tests and the pass/fail results.